# Obtener respuesta mediante ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, formularios

Tengo un problema **hipotético**:

Mipagina.php

```
 <?php if(isset($_GET['nombre']) && !empty($_GET['nombre'])) :?>
    <?php $nombre = $_GET['nombre'];?>
    Hola <?php echo $nombre;?>
<?php else:?>
    <form id="formulario">
    <input type="text" name="nombre"/>
    <button type="submit" class="consultar">Consulta tu nombre</button>
    </form>
<?php endif;?>
```

Script.js

```
$(document).on('click', '.consultar', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#formulario').submit();
});
```

Es fundamental ingresar el valor de nombre, para que muestre información.
En el caso de que no exista nombre, mostrará un formulario para consultar nombre.

**Hasta acá todo parece estar correcto, el problema comienza:**

No quiero actualizar la página al momento de ingresar el valor nombre, entonces opto por usar ajax.

Mipagina.php

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['nombre']) && !empty($_GET['nombre'])) :?>
<?php $id = $_GET['nombre'];?>
Hola <?php echo $nombre;?>
<?php else:?>
<form id="formulario">
   <input type="text" class="nombre" name="nombre"/>
   <button type="submit" class="consultar">Consulta tu nombre</button>
</form>
<div id="resultado-ajax"></div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Ajax.php

```
<?php $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
echo $nombre;?>
```

Script.js

```
$(document).on('click', '.consultar', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  consulta_Ajax();
});

function consulta_Ajax() {
  nombre = $('.nombre').val();
  $.post({
    url: 'Ajax.php',
    dataType: 'html',
    nombre: nombre, 
  }).done(function(respuesta) {
    $('#formulario').hide(); // esconde formulario
    $('#resultado-ajax').html(respuesta); // imprime respuesta
   window.history.replaceState({}  ,   ''  ,    '?nombre='+respuesta);
  });
}
```

**Tengo dos acciones:**
La primera es cuando el usuario ingresa a : Mipagina.php?nombre=Juanito
y la segunda, por si no ingresa su nombre, lo consulta mediante el formulario.

Esto funciona, pero la pregunta es:
¿Existe otro método para lograr esto?
¿Es necesario tener que escribir dos veces el resultado? URL y Ajax?

Vale!

Comment: Veo que debes definir bien las variables. `var nombre = $('.nombre').val();`.
Estás enviando como parámetro de la función `.ajax()` `nombre: nombre`. Debes enviar `data: {nombre: nombre}`. En dataType es: `dataType: "html"`.

Comment: Existen otras alternativas para realizar lo mismo, una de ellas es usar **JavaScript puro**, sin necesidad de usar jQuery. Recuerda que para esta funcionalidad que estás implementando, no necesitas cargar toda una librería, que en su interior contiene más 100 funciones en **JavaScript**, para que sólo utilices una pequeña cantidad de éstas. Lamentablemente no puedo añadir una respuesta para mostrarte un ejemplo.

Comment: gracias!
Lo que quiero lograr es no volver a escribir el resultado en dos partes distintas, pero quizás es imposible.

ya en ajax.php despliego la información mediante POST, y luego si el usuario refresca la página por ABC motivos, obtiene la información mediante GET

Answer (score 5, accepted):

viendo tu codigo asi se me ocurre ayudarte con esa guia a ver si te puede solucionar mejor el problema que indicas

```
if(isset($_GET['nombre']) && !empty($_GET['nombre'])){

   $nb="Hola '.$_GET['nombre'].'";

   }else{

   $nb="<form id='formulario'>
   <input type='text' class='nombre' id='nombre' name='nombre'/>
   <button type='submit' id='btn' class='consultar'>Consulta tu nombre</button>
</form>";

   }
```

**//para el script haria algo como esto**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#btn").onclick(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"Ajax.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data:"nombre="+$("#nombre").val(),
                        success: function(){
                            $("#resultado-ajax").html(opciones);
                        }
                    })
                });
            });
        </script>
```

**//donde se depositara la respuesta**

```
<div id="resultado-ajax"><?php echo $nb?></div>
```

Comment: omg! estuve dos días tratando de entender el proceso!
muchas gracias máquina!